# Counting number of times a pattern shows up in a dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, count

So let's say I have the following dataset:

```
keycard=c("a","b","c","b","c","b","c","a","b")
```

I want to count the number of times "bc" shows up in the vector. How can I do this?

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question?

Comment: I deleted it because I didn't phrase the question and the body paragraph in a way that was helpful for my problem. So I decided to ask a new question.

Comment: You click "edit" on your question not delete. The question had answers(in comments) that people took time to provide. The more questions you delete, the higher the chances of getting banned from asking(I think, has happened to me before). You should use those answers and modify them as necessary. The only difference is that you now provide num rather than chr data.

Comment: You're right and I'm sorry to you and to everyone who took the time to help me out. I won't do it again. I had edited the question multiple times and I felt that instead of continuing to edit it would be better if I just asked the question anew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can collapse your `keycard` vector and process it by using pattern matching with `grepRaw()` function:

```
s <- paste(keycard, collapse = "")

length( grepRaw("bc", s, all = T) )
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ulises! I tried it out and it works! This was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could do a little function like below where `vec` is your vector, `number` the number you're looking for, and `beg` and `end` the beginning and end of the vector where you're looking for it:

```
sum_occurences <- function(vec, number, beg, end) {

  accum <- Reduce(paste0, vec[beg:end], accumulate = T)

  last_two <- substr(accum, nchar(accum) - 1, nchar(accum))

  return(sum(last_two == as.character(number)))

}
```

Which you can apply as:

```
keycard = c(4,5,2,5,2,4,6,5,2)

sum_occurences(keycard, 52, 1, 5)

[1] 2
```